# WSO2IS passport-saml SLO, Error in constructing AuthRequest from the encoded String

Tags: passport-saml, wso2-identity-server

I'm currently using WSO2-IS 5.4.1 with passport-saml to implement SSO and SLO. While single sign on is working correctly, I can't seem to properly configure for complete single logout.

I'm confused on a few things to be honest

1. Why is WSO2IS sending a logout request to the SP which initiated the logout? This action is NOT captured in a SAML request but IS stated in the IdP terminal error seen below.
2. Does samlStrategy.logout also perform local logout or merely build the request and redirect to WSO2IS, it seems to be the later when I log the request? I ask because all the sample code I've reviewed contains req.logout() in the logout callback but I'm getting req.isAuthenticated() as false BEFORE I req.logout() in /wso2app/logout/callback post.

The app correctly redirects to the WSO2IS saml url and WSO2IS posts back to the callback in my app config. WSO2IS also successfully logs the user out, but seems to be sending an unnecessary SLO request back to the node app. See image link below for node SP config in IdP.

[Node app config in WSO2IS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6Y61.png)

The main error generated in IdP terminal with saml DEBUG:

> [2018-05-01 10:44:47,135] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet} - 
>   Query string :
>   slo=true&SAMLRequest=nVFLS8QwEP4rJfdtm272NbRdF4pQWD2oePAioc26hTRTM1P15xu7KyyCHoS5ZOZ7ZSbffvQ2ejOeOnSFkHEqtmVOurcD7PEFR74zr6MhjgLOEUyTQozeAWrqCJzuDQE3cL%2B72UMWpzB4ZGzQigvK3wxNZDyHACKqq0I8b5aLTaN0dlCtXmmZzlu1FtHjd8hACUCi0dSOWDsOrVSuZ%2BlilsoHqUCFWsUyWz6JqArZO6d5Yh6ZB4Iksdhoe0Ri2Cg1T74SEuGWLBbsRyNOG4DJw%2F%2FjG%2BU7YaaHIU8udM6it4FXV9E1%2Bl7z74IyllOna2eHCQqm153dta03RKIcg5e86sICZNxgf3Y6iZen148Llp8%3D
>   [2018-05-01 10:44:47,140] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.builders.SignKeyDataHolder} - 
>   Initializing Key Data for super tenant using system key store
>   [2018-05-01 10:44:47,163] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet} - 
>   Query string :
>   slo=true&SAMLRequest=nVFLS8QwEP4rJfdtm272NbRdF4pQWD2oePAioc26hTRTM1P15xu7KyyCHoS5ZOZ7ZSbffvQ2ejOeOnSFkHEqtmVOurcD7PEFR74zr6MhjgLOEUyTQozeAWrqCJzuDQE3cL%2B72UMWpzB4ZGzQigvK3wxNZDyHACKqq0I8b5aLTaN0dlCtXmmZzlu1FtHjd8hACUCi0dSOWDsOrVSuZ%2BlilsoHqUCFWsUyWz6JqArZO6d5Yh6ZB4Iksdhoe0Ri2Cg1T74SEuGWLBbsRyNOG4DJw%2F%2FjG%2BU7YaaHIU8udM6it4FXV9E1%2Bl7z74IyllOna2eHCQqm153dta03RKIcg5e86sICZNxgf3Y6iZen148Llp8%3D
>   [2018-05-01 10:44:47,169] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.logout.LogoutRequestSender} -  A
>   logoutReqSenderTask is assigned to the thread pool [2018-05-01
>   10:44:47,169] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.session.SSOSessionPersistenceManager}
>   -  Retrieved session index from session id with session index 6ffb8168-3022-4d77-9ecc-3bc168d6c5da [2018-05-01 10:44:47,345] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.logout.LogoutRequestSender} - 
>   single logout request is sent to :
>   http://localhost:3000/wso2app/logout/callback is returned with Moved
>   Temporarily [2018-05-01 10:44:47,348] DEBUG
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.util.SAMLSSOUtil} -  Request
>   message ��u�����)ඈm������,�}4��.qǬ��Z�� [Fatal Error] :1:1:
>   Content is not allowed in prolog. [2018-05-01 10:44:47,368] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.util.SAMLSSOUtil} -  Error in
>   constructing AuthRequest from the encoded String
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.  at
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.util.SAMLSSOUtil.unmarshall(SAMLSSOUtil.java:298)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.logout.LogoutRequestSender$LogoutReqSenderTask.validateResponse(LogoutRequestSender.java:280)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.logout.LogoutRequestSender$LogoutReqSenderTask.run(LogoutRequestSender.java:234)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [2018-05-01 10:44:47,376]
>   ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.logout.LogoutRequestSender} -
>   Error sending logout requests to :
>   http://localhost:3000/wso2app/logout/callback
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityException: Error in constructing
>   AuthRequest from the encoded String   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityException.error(IdentityException.java:60)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.util.SAMLSSOUtil.unmarshall(SAMLSSOUtil.java:305)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.logout.LogoutRequestSender$LogoutReqSenderTask.validateResponse(LogoutRequestSender.java:280)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.logout.LogoutRequestSender$LogoutReqSenderTask.run(LogoutRequestSender.java:234)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.  at
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.util.SAMLSSOUtil.unmarshall(SAMLSSOUtil.java:298)
>     ... 7 more

Node app. Note user1 is immediately redirected to /wso2app/logout once authenticated by IdP, this is just for testing.

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const SamlStrategy = require('passport-saml').Strategy;
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();

// logger middleware
function logger(req,res,next){
    console.log(req.method, req.url);
    next();
}
app.use(logger);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));

// express Session
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// passport middleware
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

const samlStrategy = new SamlStrategy({
    issuer: 'wso2app',

    // login endpoints
    entryPoint: 'https://localhost:9443/samlsso',   
    callbackUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/wso2app/login/callback',

    // logout endpoints
    logoutUrl: 'https://localhost:9443/samlsso?slo=true',
    logoutCallbackUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/success', 
    },
    function(profile, done){        

        return done(null,{      

            // subject claim, SAML:1.1 dialect  
            Email: profile.nameID,

            // requested claims, WSO2 internal dialect
            FirstName: profile['http://wso2.org/claims/givenname'], 
            LastName: profile['http://wso2.org/claims/lastname'],           
            Organization: profile['http://wso2.org/claims/organization'],
            Role: profile['http://wso2.org/claims/role'],

            // slo attributes
            nameID: profile.nameID,
            nameIDFormat: profile.nameIDFormat          
        });
    }); 
passport.use(samlStrategy);


app.get('/wso2app/login',   
    passport.authenticate('saml', {
        successRedirect: '/wso2app',
        failureRedirect: '/wso2app/login'       
    })
);  

app.post('/wso2app/login/callback', passport.authenticate('saml', { 
    failureRedirect: '/wso2app/login',
    failureFlash: true, 
    }),
    function(req, res){
        res.redirect('/wso2app')        
    }
);

app.get('/wso2app', function(req, res) {

    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {       
        res.redirect('/wso2app/login');     
    }

    //parse domain from the user's email attribute in SAML response
    const domain = req.user.Email.substring(req.user.Email.lastIndexOf("@") + 1);
    console.log(domain);https://localhost:9443/samlsso?slo=true

    //use domain as index router, send specific users to their respective url
    switch(domain){
        case 'inst1.com':
            console.log(JSON.stringify(req.user));
            //res.redirect('/wso2app/inst1/');
            res.redirect('/wso2app/logout');
            break;
        case 'unv2.edu':
            console.log(JSON.stringify(req.user));
            res.redirect('/wso2app/unv2/');
            break;
        case 'inst3.com':
            console.log(JSON.stringify(req.user));
            res.redirect('/wso2app/inst3/');
            break;
        default:
            res.send("You're Authenticated but Unaffiliated, Your Credentials: " + JSON.stringify(req.user));
    }       
});

app.get('/wso2app/logout', function(req, res){

    console.log("req.user.nameID: " + req.user.nameID);
    console.log("req.user.nameIDFormat: " + req.user.nameIDFormat); 
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        console.log("Still Auth in Node 1");        
    }

    samlStrategy.logout(req, function(err, request){
        if (!err) {
            res.redirect(request);
            console.log('request: ' + request);
        }       
    }); 
});

app.post('/wso2app/logout/callback', function(req,res){ 
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {       
        console.log("Already logged out");
    }
    req.logout();   
    res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/success');
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server Started on Port 3000');
});
```

[SLO request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPjOl.pnghttp://xacmlinfo.org/2013/06/28/how-saml2-single-logout-works/) Note: This is the proper SLO request sent by the node app to the IdP which is captured by SAML browser tool. The mystery slo request sent back to app from IdP is only documented in IdP terminal error.

I've reviewed multiple posts but can't find one related to my issue. The cryptic nature of the logout request sent to http://localhost:3000/wso2app/logout/callback is concerning, but again I don't understand why this is even being sent. This seems to not follow the official SLO flow depicted [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/06/28/how-saml2-single-logout-works/) I've read that the "[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog." is related to excessive white space characters, I'm not sure how, or why, this request is being generated? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: By looking at the log, this is what seems to be happening.

Say you have enable SSO for 2 applications (foo and bar) and you have logged in to both of these applications. Now you initiate a logout request from foo app. Upon successful logout, IS will be sending a backchannel logout request to bar app to indicate the IDP side session is removed.

In your case, IS seems to be sending a logout request to the logout endpoint of bar app and the bar app is not sending a valid response, hence the error.

Do you have multiple apps registered with IS having the same logout url ?

Comment: I do not. Currently, I don't have multiple apps at all, only one single app. But as you say, it seems to be receiving a logout request and isn't able to send a valid response.

Am I correct in assuming that this single app should not be receiving a logout request from IS due to it being the application that initiated the logout?